# Assigning events to elements from getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript:

```
var myArr = document.getElementsByClassName('contItm');

for(i=0;i<myArr.length;i++){
    myArr[i].onmouseover = function(){
        document.getElementById(myArr[i].id + 'Mnu').style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="contMnu">
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="reqAcct" class="contItm">Accounts & Access</a>
        <ul id="reqAcctMnu" class="subContMnu" style="background-color:#cdcdcd">
            <li><a href="#" class="tab">Sub1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="tab">sub2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is basically assign a function that will take in the ID of the href and add "Mnu" to it to target the ID of the ul below.

If I were writing this inside of each element this is how it would display but i want it to dynamically be added to all items with the classname

```
<a href="#" id="reqAcct" class="contItm" onmouseover="showMnu(this.id)">Accounts & Access</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with the famous "i" in the loop where it will be equal to myArr.length when the method is called. Below is one way around the problem.

```
var myArr = document.getElementsByClassName('contItm');

for(i=0;i<myArr.length;i++){
    (function (elem) {
        elem.onmouseover = function(){
            document.getElementById(elem.id + 'Mnu').style.display = "inline";
        };
    })(myArr[i]);
}
```

without the reference to the elem, you can just use `this.id` inside

```
for(i=0;i<myArr.length;i++){
    myArr[i].onmouseover = function(){
        document.getElementById(this.id + 'Mnu').style.display = "inline";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind the event to a parent element:

**HTML**:

```
<ul id="contMnu" class="contMnu"> ... </ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var menu = document.getElementById("contMnu");

menu.onmouseover = function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
};
```

Using `e.target` to get the element that moused over and doing your logic there.

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yMm5b/)